# Set-ADUser address attribute using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script that I use to create new AD users. The basic script works great and gets me to where I need to be when I create a new user. There is one part that is missing that I would like to have automated so that I wont have to update the info manually. I need to add the address and phone number for a user based on their location. From the code below, I added the if elseif statement. What I have below gives the error - *The term 'Austin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.* Obviously the variable $location doesn't work with the script, however, I am not as familar with PowerShell to see where to correct this or if there should be better way to write this out. Should I add Get-ADUser in front of it to pull the user info once its been added? Or add the if, elseif at the end of the script?

```
#Prompt for user information
$first = Read-Host "First name"
$last = Read-Host "Last name"
$title = Read-Host "Title"
$location = Read-Host "Location (location1,location2)"
$department = Read-Host "Business Practice"
$password = read-host -assecurestring "Password"

if($location = location1) {
    Set-ADUser -street "StreetName" -city "City" -state "State" -postalcode "Zip" -officephone "Phone"
}
elseif($location = location2) {
    Set-ADUser -street "StreetName" -city "City" -state "State" -postalcode "Zip" -officephone "Phone"
}



#Create new user

$Attributes = @{
                    
   Enabled = $true
   ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
   UserPrincipalName = $first.substring(0,1)+$last+"@domain.com"
   Name = $first + " " + $last
   GivenName = $first
   Surname = $last
   DisplayName = $first + " " + $last
   Office = $location
   Department = $department
   Title = $title
   samAccountName = $first.substring(0,1)+$last
   emailaddress = $first.substring(0,1)+$last+"@domain.com"
   AccountPassword = $password
   Path = "OU Path"
   

}

New-ADUser @Attributes
```

Comment: you are using `=` instead of `-eq`. [*grin*] ///// also, you are using `$Location` - which is a STRING - for your comparison. you likely want to split that string, trim away any extra whitespace, and then use `$Location[0]` for the 1st item. ///// also also, you never validate the input. you really otta do that. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the info. Question - what do you mean when you say "split that string"? Also, for validating data, would this be some that I would do using a separate function instead or do it line by line?

Comment: you told the user to input `LocationOne, LocationTwo` ... and that is a string with a coma in the middle. so, to get the values into two parts, you need to split it with something like `$LocationString.Split(,)`  - and likely need to trim away any unwanted spaces. ///// for validation, i would likely make getting the location a function & include the validation in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Set-ADUser` needs to know the user for which these properties need to be set through its `Identity` parameter which is missing
2. You can simply add these properties to the `$Attributes` hashtable you use for the `New-ADUser` cmdlet.
   You just need to define some logic as to where these properties come from.

Something like using a switch:

```
# with '$location'  just ask for the city:
$location = Read-Host "City"

# I'm making this up of course
switch ($location) {
    'Austin' { 
        $city        = 'Austin'
        $state       = 'Texas'
        $postalcode  = '73301'
        $officephone = '555-123456'
        break
    }
    'Salt Lake City' {
        $city        = 'Salt Lake City'
        $state       = 'Utah'
        $postalcode  = '84044'
        $officephone = '555-654321'
        break
    }
    default { $city = $null }
}

if ($city) {
    $Attributes = @{
       Enabled                             = $true
       ChangePasswordAtLogon               = $false
       UserPrincipalName                   = $first.substring(0,1)+$last+"@domain.com"
       Name                                = $first + " " + $last
       GivenName                           = $first
       Surname                             = $last
       DisplayName                         = $first + " " + $last
       Office                              = $location
       Department                          = $department
       Title                               = $title
       samAccountName                      = $first.substring(0,1)+$last
       emailaddress                        = $first.substring(0,1)+$last+"@domain.com"
       AccountPassword                     = $password
       Path                                = "OU Path"
       # these are from the switch() above
       City                                = $city
       State                               = $state
       PostalCode                          = $postalcode
       OfficePhone                         = $officephone
    }

    New-ADUser @Attributes
}
```

Or you can create a CSV file like

```
City,State,PostalCode,OfficePhone
Austin,Texas,73301,555-123456
Salt Lake City,Utah,84044,555-654321
```

and read that using

```
$locations = Import-Csv -Path '<PathToTheLocations.csv>'

# with '$location'  just ask for the city:
$location = Read-Host "City"

# then get the address info from there based on the given city
$address = $locations | Where-Object { $_.City -eq $location }

if ($address) {
    $Attributes = @{
       Enabled                  = $true
       ChangePasswordAtLogon    = $false
       UserPrincipalName        = $first.substring(0,1)+$last+"@domain.com"
       Name                     = $first + " " + $last
       GivenName                = $first
       Surname                  = $last
       DisplayName              = $first + " " + $last
       Office                   = $location
       Department               = $department
       Title                    = $title
       samAccountName           = $first.substring(0,1)+$last
       emailaddress             = $first.substring(0,1)+$last+"@domain.com"
       AccountPassword          = $password
       Path                     = "OU Path"
       # these are from the CSV
       City                     = $address.City
       State                    = $address.State
       PostalCode               = $address.PostalCode
       OfficePhone              = $address.OfficePhone
    }

    New-ADUser @Attributes
}
```

Of course, **NEVER** trust user input from Read-Host and build in some validation checks before creating a new user

Comment: This worked like a champ. Appreciate the help. Now I have to work on the validation and the add-distributiongroupmember functions and I should be all set. Thanks again.